# Mongoose query gives undefined error on push but appears normal on console.log

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Hello I am pushing data to an array within a document inside my mongodb.

It is a report nosql document that has a response array inside that I will push comments to on this specific report page but I am getting the following error:

```
(node:3206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
Report.findOne({urlString: req.params.id}, async (err, report) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);

            console.log({report});
            await {report}.response.push(newResponse);

            res.redirect('/reports/' + {report}.urlString);
        });
```

The console.log prints this out so I am unsure how report.response can be undefined.

[image]

Comment: In that console.log, try logging just the response field.

Comment: not sure why you need to await when pushing the value into the array? or even async await the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

just a bit of clean up(removing curly brackets), not sure why async/await is necessary, you can just do:

```
Report.findOne({urlString: req.params.id}, (err, report) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);

            //console.log({report});
            report.response.push(newResponse);

            res.redirect('/reports/' + report.urlString);
        });
```